# JSP page is not working after changing the Context root

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, jsp, web

I have created a simple JSP page inside webapp which uses jquery, CSS and Angular JS. All of the **jquery-1.12.0.js**, **angular.min.js** and **TableCSSCode.css** are in the same location where JSP page reside. Initially my application context was **mycontext**, so the URL of my utility was **http://10.28.27.10:7006/mycontext/myTool.jsp**.

Later I have to change my context from **mycontext** to **test/newcontext/mycontext**. After doing the same I am able to launch new URL i.e **http://10.28.27.10:7006/test/newcontext/mycontext/myTool.jsp** but JSP is not  able read jquery, CSS and Angular JS.

Below is the line of code I am using:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/angular.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/TableCSSCode.css">
```

Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: Try cleaning you project once and retry

Comment: I did everything. I have restarted the server too.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using relative path. If your files are in same location no need to give whole context path.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="TableCSSCode.css">
```

Comment: awe sorry for that. I will try a hands on example if possible to make it work for you.